# Is it possible to do a POST request without acessToken with google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I want to upload data in google sheet by rest API with only sheet id from shared link. I of course expecting that user will grand general access as editor for anyone with the link.
I managed to get data with sheet id from the shared link thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets), but for upload data I only find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331104/send-request-body-to-a-google-sheet-using-sheets-api-and-xmlhttprequest) which requires accessToken. Is it possible to edit content of google sheet with rest API in javascript without authentication or access Token if permission is editing access is granted to anyone with shared link?